# multiple .sorted(...) calls on java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Stream of objects that I want to sort naturally, but also force one of the members to always be first.

For example:

```
List<String> result = Stream.of("a", "s", "d", "f")
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.equals("d"))
                            .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
        .collect(toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

This produces

```
[d, a, f, s]
```

That is, alphabetical but with "d" first.

I noticed that I can also write this using multiple `.sorted(...)` calls:

```
List<String> result = Stream.of("a", "s", "d", "f")
        .sorted()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> !s.equals("d")))
        .collect(toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

This produces the same result, and is IMO more readable.

However, I don't see examples of anyone else doing it this way.

Furthermore, IntelliJ IDEA flags the first `.sorted()` call as redundant.  It says the "subsequent 'sorted' call makes sorting useless".

This is demonstrably untrue, as removing the call changes the output to

```
[d, a, s, f]
```

So my question is:  are multiple `.sorted(...)` calls on a Stream defined behavior, or am I just getting lucky?

In other words, is this a supported use of `.sorted()` that I can depend on, or does it only happen to work now and might stop working in some future release of Java?

Comment: Develop your end sentence please, it is actually not clear what you're asking in my opinion. What do you mean by *defined behavior* and by *getting lucky* ?

Comment: Edited with some elaboration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "defined", I am assuming you're asking "is the sort stable"? if so then yes it's.

The first `sorted()` call of the second example snippet will sort the elements according to the natural order and then sorts *again* according to the provided comparator.

The issue with the second approach is that it's *inefficient* as it requires two sorting operations, for that reason one may decide to proceed with the first approach.

Comment: I'm not really asking if it's stable.  I'm asking if this is a supported use of .sorted(), or if it just "accidentally" works now and might stop working in a future release.  For example, given Intellij's warning, I could imagine that future Java might optimize away the first sort.

Comment: @AlexWittig In some cases streams can utilise their knowledge of the source and previous operations to omit an operation entirely. but in this particular case `sorted()` and `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> !s.equals("d")))` are two different things as the former sorts by natural order whereas the second is by the provided comparator. I don't expect any future version to omit the first `sorted` call. if we had `.sorted().sorted()` then it would make more sense to omit the second call to `sorted`.

Comment: @AlexWittig The only case where it would make sense to optimse the stream pipeline by eliding a `sorted` operation is if it's known that the elements are already sorted in natural order and you want to chain "another" natural order sort and hence the subsequent `sorted` can become a no-op. That said, you might find [this post ](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-java-streams-3-brian-goetz/index.html) about flags and how sometimes some intermediate operations can be elided completely of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful.  So basically, no one else does it this way because it's less efficient, but otherwise it's an acceptable solution.

Comment: @AlexWittig in terms of "why everyone does it this way", I can only speak for myself and I'd proceed with `.sorted(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.equals("d")).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))` as it's more efficient and makes more sense as opposed to the double sort, but yes `.sorted()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> !s.equals("d")))` is perfectly acceptable and  in this specific case _I_ would not expect the first `sorted` operation to be elided just because intelliJ "suggests" so.

Comment: @AlexWittig Sorry, just to clarify, where I said "then it would make more sense to omit the second call to sorted" I meant the "first call" and where I said "hence the subsequent sorted can become a no-op." i meant the "previous sorted call can become a no-op".

Comment: @AlexWittig “*I'm not really asking if it's stable. I'm asking if this is a supported use of .sorted(), or if it just "accidentally" works now and might stop working in a future release.*”, well then you *are* asking whether it’s stable. As a guaranteed stable sorting implies respect towards the previous order, which may be the result of a previous sorting. Since that stable sorting is guaranteed for ordered streams, the implementation can’t eliminate a preceding sorting step (with a different comparator), as that would be a semantic change.

Comment: @Holger what sucks, is that `...sorted()...sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())` will perform two sort operations - I don't use that, but just the thought of it..

Comment: @Eugene there’s generally no support for comparing comparators there (I’ve never seen a convincing explanation for not supporting it), the fact that “no comparator” and “`naturalOrder()`” are not recognized to be the same, is just another quirk.